# Is there a way to pushState() the parent window in facebook canvas?

Tags: facebook, iframe, same-origin-policy, facebook-canvas, pushstate

I want my facebook canvas app to be able to update the address bar URL when changing context. So, for example, if my app's home URL is `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/`, and the user clicks on some item on the home screen, I'd like the URL shown in the address bar to change to `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/1/` or `https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/#1`.

Normally, my app could do that with HTML5's `history.pushState()`. Problem is, the canvas app runs inside an iframe, and cannot access the parent window's `pushState` (because the iframe is not the same domain as apps.facebook.com). Another technique should be changing just the hash part of the address, i.e. `window.location.hash = "1"`, but that too is not possible from within the iframe, for the same reason.

It is possible to change the parent page URL with reloading the entire page, by using

```
window.parent.location = "https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/1/"
```

However, this would cause the parent page to reload, taking up a good number of seconds, and then reload the iframe - all in all, a very long and frustrating experience for the user.

Could there be a way of doing this I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain there is no way to do this without special help from Facebook's end. For example Facebook could implement a script on the canvas page which utilizes `postMessage` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) to listen for cross-domain messages from your iframe.

But without cooperation from Facebook, I don't think any modern, standard browser will allow you to do this.

Comment: You're right. Unfortunately, Facebook API does not have such method, even though IMHO it is a rather simple method to add, assuming that verifying the domain prefix matches is good enough protection against XSS. If you think you could find such API useful for your uses, please vote for this with FB: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/133461353503702

Comment: +1ed it. Seems like they're leaving it on the "wishlist" for now though.